# Why does C outputs gibberish results when operation on an integer greater than 10 digits?

Tags: c, long-integer

The code given below works fine up-to 10 digits with (`int` data-type) , but for numbers exceeding 10 digits it failed , so i tried `unsigned long long int`. But now my output is fixed to 15 , idk why? Consider me very new to C , i have mediocre python background though!

I am using gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.1) 5.4.0 20160609

```
#include <stdio.h> //Get number of digits in a int
unsigned long long int get_len();

void main() {
    unsigned long long int num;
    printf("Enter the number:");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    printf("\nThe length of number is is: %d \n",get_len(num));
}

unsigned long long int get_len(unsigned long long int z) {
    unsigned long long int i = 1;
    while (1) {
        if ((z/10) > 1) {
            //printf("Still greater than 1");
            i++;
                        z = z/10;
            continue;}
        else {
            return(i+1);
                        break;}}}
```

Comment: You may want some [bignum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) library like [GMPlib](http://gmplib.org/)

Comment: Save time, enable all compiler warnings.

Comment: Python automatically switches to bignums when required, but C is "closer to the metal" and any given type of number cannot be promoted to a larger one when necessary. So even if you correct your code to work with `unsigned long long int`, which is 64 bits in modern compilers, you can't cross *its* limit of 20 decimals.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have used wrong format specifier. it would be  `scanf("%llu",&num);`

Using the wrong format specifer in `scanf` is undefined behavior.

Apart from what is being mentioned, your length finding logic is wrong in that it will fail for single digit numbers and also for multidigit one.

For `1` it will return number of digits `2` and similarly for other numbers. (like for `12` it will return `3`).

For larger numbers you will have options of opting an library (big number processing) or write one of as you need.

<sub>I would scan the numbers like this 
`if( scanf("%llu",&num) != 1) { /* error */}`. More clearly check the return value of `scanf`.</sub>

Comment: God, never tried a single digit number , but yeah it did fail , I'll do the correction! Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2):

Here's another implementation. This fixes a few issues:

1. Main return type must be `int`.
2. `unsigned int` is more than sufficient as `get_len()` return type.
3. `unsigned int` and `unsigned` are the same. Also `unsigned long long int` can be stripped of `int`.

> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> unsigned get_len();
>
> int main()
> {
>     unsigned long long num;
>
>     printf("Enter the number: ");
>     scanf("%llu", &num);
>
>     printf("\nThe length of number is: %u\n", get_len(num));
> }
>
> unsigned get_len(unsigned long long z)
> {
>     return (z / 10 > 0) ? get_len(z / 10) + 1 : 1;
> }
> ```